# Infinite pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[Infinite Atwood Machine Harvard Solution](http://webdev.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/probweek/sol43.pdf)

Hi, I've been trying to solve this question for a while. I understand the first solution and also the solution to the second problem but I don't understand how to apply the second problem to solve the infinite pulley system.

In particular, I don't understand the last sentences:

> Therefore, since $f N (x) → 3m$ as $N →∞$, our infinite Atwood’s machine
> is equivalent to (as far as the top mass is concerned) just two masses, $m$ and $3m$. **You can then quickly show that the acceleration of the top mass is $g/2$.**

> Note that as far as the support is concerned, the whole apparatus is equivalent to a mass $3m$. So $3mg$ is the upward force exerted by the support.

If the Atwood's machine is equivalent to just two masses $m$ and $3 m$, then wouldn't the value of acceleration be $2g$?

Answer (score 1):

No, an Atwood's machine with masses $m$ and $3m$ has acceleration of $g \frac{3m -m}{3m+m} = g/2$, as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atwood_machine#Equation_for_constant_acceleration

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple diagram of the Atwood machine you describe.

### [image: simple diagram]

For reference:
$F_{total} = m_{total} \cdot a$

---

Let us call $g$ the gravitational acceleration, $m$ the mass of the less massive "block," and $a$ the acceleration of the "duel-block-system."

---

$$F_{total} = m_{total} \cdot a$$
$$a = \frac{F_{total}}{m_{total}}
= \frac{F_{m} + F_{3m}}{3m + m}
= \frac{-mg + 3mg}{4m}
= \frac{2mg}{4m}
= \frac{g}{2}$$

---

For more complicated Atwood machines, use a similar method.